# Como fixar pontos de intersecção para calcular a distância entre pontos?

Tags: oracle

Preciso calcular a distância entre pontos dentro do local onde trabalho, para isso calculei as coordenadas de cada local em X e Y e lancei as coordenadas no sistema.

Estou fazendo uma `query` para calcular essa distância, porem como não é sempre em uma linha reta que será feito os calcular eu tive que colocar pontos de interseção para calcular quando ele sai de uma rua e vai para outra,

> Por exemplo: De 1AF-001-10 para 1AD-013-10 ele sai da rua "AF" e vai
>   para rua "AD".

Para isso ele precisa calcular assim :

```
De            Para
1AF-001-10  || interseçãoAF = valor1

    De            Para
interseçãoAF || interseçãoAD = valor2

    De            Para
interseçãoAD || 1AD-013-10 = valor3

Ou seja :
    De           Para
1AF-001-10 || 1AD-013-10 = soma(valor1,valor2,valor3)
```

Eu consegui chegara no calculo em linha reta, usei o case com substr dizendo que se as siglas das rua inicial for igual a final ele faz o calculo e não sei como colocar no else como ele tem que proceder com os demais cálculos.

Abaixo segue a query :

```
[Select 

local_inicial,
local_final,
case when substr(local_inicial,2,2) = substr(local_final,2,2) then Round (SQRT (POWER (eixoxf - eixoxi,2) + POWER (eixoyf - eixoyi,2)))*1.2 else 0 end  as "dist",
carton,
usuario,
tempoi,
tempof

From
(Select
linhas,
loci as local_inicial,
LEAD(loci, 1,loci) OVER (PARTITION BY usu,hh,dia1 ORDER BY linhas) as local_final,
ctn as carton,
usu as usuario,
hhmmssi as tempoi,
LEAD(hhmmssi, 1,hhmmssi) OVER (PARTITION BY usu,hh,dia1 ORDER BY linhas) as tempof,
exi as eixoxi,
LEAD(exi, 1,exi) OVER (PARTITION BY usu,hh,dia1 ORDER BY linhas) as eixoxf,
eyi as eixoyi,
LEAD(eyi, 1,eyi) OVER (PARTITION BY usu,hh,dia1 ORDER BY linhas) as eixoyf

From
(Select 
rownum as linhas, 
D.frstol as loci,
D.To_subnum as ctn,
D.usr_id as usu,
To_Char (D.trndte, 'HH24') as hh,
To_Char (D.trndte, 'DD') as dia1,
To_Char (D.ins_dt, 'HH24:MI:SS') as hh24,
To_Char (D.ins_dt, 'HH24') *3600 + To_Char (D.ins_dt, 'MI') *3600/60 + To_Char (D.ins_dt, 'SS') as hhmmssi,
Substr(L.top_left_x,1,2) as exi,
Substr(L.top_left_y,1,2) as eyi

From DLYTRN D, LOCMST L
Where D.WH_ID = L.WH_ID
And D.frstol = L.stoloc
And D.trndte >= trunc (sysdate) -5
And D.oprcod = 'UPK'
And D.actcod in ('CASPCK','PLAPCK','OTRPCK')
And D.usr_id <> all ('EDREIS','ARSILVA','EGONCALVES','AAKOJO')
And D.usr_id = 'ADFLORENCIO'
And L.top_left_x > '0'
And L.top_left_y > '0'
Order By D.usr_id, To_Char (D.trndte, 'DD'), To_Char (D.ins_dt, 'HH24:MI:SS')))
```

Eu pensei em fazer uma outra `query` dentro do case dizendo que se a sigla do local inicial for "X" ele precisa passar pelos pontos de interseção "A","B" etc. e no final somar os dois. mas não sei como fazer.

Query que trás só os pontos de interseção :

```
[Select  
Substr(stoloc,2,2) as inter,
Substr(L.top_left_x,1,2) as exi, 
Substr(L.top_left_y,1,2) as eyi 

From LOCMST L 
Where L.top_left_x > '0' 
And L.top_left_y > '0' 
And L.stoloc like '1%PD-%'
```

A baixo segue uma imagem do layout para ficar mais fácil o entendimento referente aos pontos de interseção.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você esta usando 3 bancos de dados?

Comment: Não não é apenas um amigo.

Comment: mysql sql sql-server oracle ?

Comment: Isso são apenas os tags que coloquei, o banco que eu uso aceita um pouco de cada linguagem

Comment: Sim, as tags tem relação com o que você usar, se tive uma resposta com mysql e seu banco for oracle vai ter muita coisa na query não não vai ser aceita no ultimo banco, ou seja use as tags que tem relação direta com seu problema.

Comment: Entendi, desculpa ai, eu estou aprendendo ainda, na verdade até hoje aprendi só lendo não tenho conhecimento técnico, sei que nosso banco é oracle, sql eu sei que roda nele normal pq faço todas as query com linguagem de sql sei que ele aceita algumas outras linguagens

Comment: o [SQL](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) é genérico, veja na tag suas regras para uso. alterei sua tag para oracle que no caso é a mais correta.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi você deseja percorrer uma rota de ruas pré-definidas e pegar o total gasto na distância, correto? Você teria as coordenadas de-para de cada intersecção da rua em uma tabela? Neste caso, se o seu oracle for !!g para cima, poderia ser utilizado um bloco with com SEARCH BREADTH FIRST